# Reinforcement Learning with Keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I was trying to implement a q-learning algorithms in Keras. According to the articles i found these lines of code.

```
for state, action, reward, next_state, done in sample_batch:
        target = reward
        if not done:
            #formula
          target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.brain.predict(next_state)[0])
        target_f = self.brain.predict(state)
        #shape (1,2)
        target_f[0][action] = target
        print(target_f.shape)
        self.brain.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    if self.exploration_rate > self.exploration_min:
        self.exploration_rate *= self.exploration_decay
```

Variable `sample_batch` is the array that contains sample `state, action, reward, next_state, done` from collected data.
I also found the following q-learning formula [image: Formula]

Why is there no `-` sign in the equation(code)? I found out that `np.amax` returns the maximum of an array or maximum along an axis. When i call `self.brain.predict(next_state)`, I get `[[-0.06427538 -0.34116858]]`. So it plays the role of prediction  in this equation? As we go forward `target_f` is the predicted output for the current state and then we also append to it the reward with this step. Then, we train model on current `state`(`X`) and `target_f`(`Y`). I have a few questions. What is the role of `self.brain.predict(next_state)` and why there is no minus? Why do we predict twice on one model? Ex `self.brain.predict(state) and self.brain.predict(next_state)[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there no - sign in the equation(code)?

It's because loss calculation is done inside the fit function.

```
reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.brain.predict(next_state)[0])
```

This is the same as the **target** component in the loss function.

Inside the fit method in keras loss will be calculated as given below.
For a single training data point (standard notations of neural networks),

```
x = input state

y = predicted value

y_i = target value

loss(x) = y_i - y
```

at this step **target - prediction** happens internally.

> Why do we predict twice on one model?

Good question !!!

```
 target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.brain.predict(next_state)[0])
```

In this step we are predicting the value of the next state to calculate target **value for state s if we take specific action a** (which is denoted as Q(s,a) )

```
 target_f = self.brain.predict(state)
```

In this step we are calculating all the **Q values for every action** which we can take in state s.

```
target = 1.00    // target is a single value for action a
target_f = (0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)   //target_f is a list of values for all actions
```

following step is then executed.

```
target_f[0][action] = target
```

we only change the value of selected action. ( if we take action 3 )

```
target_f = (0.25,0.25,1.00,0.25)  // only action 3 value will change
```

Now target_f will be the **actual target value** we are trying to predict with correct shape.